# Cypress not able to click on google-maps element (addGeoJson) Angular

Tags: angular, google-maps, cypress, angular-google-maps

#### I'm having a very hard time trying to figure out how to test google-maps with Cypress

##### Expected Behavior:

Being able to click in the middle of the screen and trigger the `mouseclick`

##### Actual Behavior:

Cypress is clicking on the middle of the screen **BUT** not on my added entities(circles/rectangles), it seems like my entities are not even there when Cypress is clicking, but on the other hand you can see them when running the test with `npx cypress open` (will attach images for more details)

- Cypress: ^9.5.0
- @angular/google-maps: ^13.3.0

On the UI 2 things are happening:

1. Adding my own elements to the google maps
2. Adding to those elements eventListener `click`.
   **Manually everything behaves perfectly fine!**

[image]

##### Angular code adding my entities + click eventListener:

```
addDataLayer(dataLayer: google.maps.Data): void {
    dataLayer.addGeoJson(this.entitiesService.entities) // works perfectly fine
});

addDataLayerListeners(dataLayer: google.maps.Data): void {
    dataLayer.addListener('click', (event) => {
       my-function() // is working fine when i click on the UI manually
    })
});
```

#### The steps of my test

```
it('my clicking tests example 1' , () => {
    cy.createMyEntity()✅
    cy.get('body').click(400,400,{force:true})❌
 })
 it('my clicking tests example 2' , () => {
    cy.createMyEntity()✅
    cy.get('canvas').first()
     .trigger('pointerdown', {force: true, which: 1, button: 0, bubbles: false})
     .trigger('pointerup',{force: true,which: 1, button: 0, bubbles: false})❌
 })
 it('my clicking tests example 3' , () => {
    cy.createMyEntity()✅
    cy.get('canvas').first()
     .trigger('pointerdown', {force: true, which: 1, button: 0})
     .trigger('pointerup',{force: true,which: 1, button: 0})❌
 })
 it('my clicking tests example 4' , () => {
    cy.createMyEntity()✅
    cy.get('canvas').first()
     .trigger('mouseover', {force: true, which: 1, button: 0})
     .trigger('mousedown', {force: true, which: 1, button: 0})
     .trigger('mouseup',{force: true,which: 1, button: 0})❌
 })
```

### Examle of Cypress running

[image]

### And when I pin one of the test lines this is happenning

like there is no entity on the map ‍♂️
[image]

### How google render my entities inside the DOM:

[image]

##### Questions

1. is there a way to make it behave as it does manually?
2. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The map is a canvas, I don't think you can't test the fine details with Cypress.

Comment: Even when i change the `cy.get('canvas')` to `cy.get('body')` (so it will click in the middle of the screen) it does not change

Comment: That's not going to help - the canvas controls the details you want to test.

Comment: So I'm trying to understand what is the difference between cypress click to manual click, should it not be the same?

Comment: Cypress doesn't actually click the screen. It's just calling the click event on the element you give it. So if you're giving it the body element, and calling click(), it's firing the click even on the body, not the element on the canvas. 

Unfortunately you can't access much at all on the canvas. It does make testing applications that use maps heavily rather difficult.